# Why do numbers of the type (2^a)-1 become negative after a= 31?

Tags: c

I have made a C program to check the primality of numbers of the type (2^a)-1 . But after a=31, the value becomes -ve. I don't know what's wrong. I have tried both the `pow` function as well as defining the function myself but still the same output.
kindly tell me how to fix this.
The code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int is_prime(int num) {
    if (num <= 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    for (int i = 2; i<(num); i++) {
        if (num % i == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    int b=1;
     int a;

    while (b) {
       
        printf("\n Enter the value of 'a': ");
        scanf("%d",&a);

        int num=((pow(2,a))-1);
        printf("  The no. is : %d \n",num);

        if (is_prime(num)) {
            printf("\n (2^%d-1) is a prime number.\n ", a);
        } else {
            printf("\n (2^%d-1) is not a prime number.\n", a);
        }

        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output is attached.

[image]

Comment: All integer types in C have a range of values. The range for `int` is *usually* from minus two billion to plus two billion. If you need a value larger than that, you need to use a type with a larger range. This range comes from the number of bits that is used to represent the values. `int` is usually 32 bits. You can't represent a 34-bit value (2^34 - 1) with only 32 bits.

Comment: and never use `pow(2,a)` for integer powers of 2, use `1 << a` instead. See also [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714), just copy the text in the terminal and paste here in proper format

Comment: `int num=((pow(2,a))-1);` You are mixing floating point operations and integer calculations this will lead to rounding errors at some point. Never do that. Also when you look around on stack overflow you will find out this question has been asked a lot of times before

Comment: Fundamental fact of the day: C data types have [limits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits).

Comment: If you want unlimited values, there are so-called "bignum" libraries that you can use. For example [GMP](https://gmplib.org).

Comment: Watch this video on floating point numbers : [Floating Point Numbers - Computerphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0)

Comment: Bug, with 32- `int`, try `is_prime(2147483647)`

Comment: OT: your is_prime() function is very inefficient. See [primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test). Also be aware that if `a` is not a prime, then `2^a-1` is also not a prime.

Answer (score 4):

This is due to [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

The maximal value (INT_MAX) of a 32 bit integer is 2147483647.
The value `(2^32)-1` is 4294967295 and much greater than the maximal value.

If you want to store larger numbers you could use a `long long` variable, which will provide you with 64 bits.

If you do not have negative numbers you can use `unsigned long long` for the possibility of even higher numbers.
As mentioned in the comments, this is the largest type, but it can only be used to store positive numbers.

Comment: which is the biggest data type which I can use as the powers can be very big

Comment: @AkshatParmar Currently the largest type in standard C is `unsigned long long`, which is guaranteed to be *at least* 64 bits.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, since all calculations involve positive integers, an unsigned type (e.g. `unsigned long`) should be used throughout the code.

Secondly, it must be checked that the value of `a` will not cause an overflow when calculating `2^a-1`. E.g.:

```
   if(a > CHAR_BIT * sizeof(unsigned long)) printf("Error: value out of range\n");
```

Thirdly, the calculation of `num` is error-prone. It should be done as follows:

```
   unsigned long num = (a == CHAR_BIT * sizeof(unsigned long)) ? (unsigned long)-1: (1ul << a)-1;
```

Notice the corner case for the maximal value of `a`. In that case, the bit-shifting would be undefined behavior, but the wanted result is just the maximal value for `unsigned long` which can be expressed as `(unsigned long)-1`.

Comment: Is that `8` in your code a typo for `CHAR_BIT`?  And `>` a typo for `>=`?

Comment: @TobySpeight You are right, `CHAR_BIT` is more correct, I have changed that - thanks. `>` is not a typo. We need the value `2^a-1` which can be represented as long as `a` does not strictly exceed the bit width, but the maximal value needs to be treated specially as already explained.

Comment: Yes, I missed that 1 is subtracted before conversion to `int`.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to correct this is to change the type of the variable a to unsigned long (or uint64_t if you include <stdint.h>)

However keep in mind that even using this approach you will again encounter the same problem when a exceeds 64 due to integer overflow.

You are better off using some other big number library if you want to really do this for big numbers greater than 2**64

Comment: How can I use array for very big values?